# Azure VMSS with Custom Image using Powershell returned error: DiskProcessingError

Tags: azure, cloud, azure-virtual-machine

I am having problem deploying vmss using custom images via powershell. The following is my code for the powershell deployment:

```
#New-AzureRmResourceGroup -Location southeastasia -Name arkgenegroup1
# Resource group name from above
$rg = "myvmss"
$location = "southeastasia"

# Create a config object
$vmssConfig = New-AzureRmVmssConfig -Location $location -SkuCapacity 2 -SkuName Standard_A0  -UpgradePolicyMode Automatic 

# Reference a virtual machine image from the gallery
Set-AzureRmVmssStorageProfile -VirtualMachineScaleSet $vmssConfig -OsDiskCreateOption FromImage -ManagedDisk StandardLRS -OsDiskCaching "None" -OsDiskOsType Linux -ImageReferenceId (Get-AzureRmImage -ImageName image200817 -ResourceGroupName $rg).id


# Set up information for authenticating with the virtual machine
Set-AzureRmVmssOsProfile $vmssConfig -AdminUsername admin -AdminPassword adminpass -ComputerNamePrefix myvmss

# Create the virtual network resources

## Basics
$subnet = New-AzureRmVirtualNetworkSubnetConfig -Name "my-subnet" -AddressPrefix 10.0.0.0/24
$vnet = New-AzureRmVirtualNetwork -Name "my-network" -ResourceGroupName $rg -Location $location -AddressPrefix 10.0.0.0/16 -Subnet $subnet

## Load balancer
$publicIP = New-AzureRmPublicIpAddress -Name "PublicIP" -ResourceGroupName $rg -Location $location -AllocationMethod Static -DomainNameLabel "myuniquedomain"
$frontendIP = New-AzureRmLoadBalancerFrontendIpConfig -Name "LB-Frontend" -PublicIpAddress $publicIP
$backendPool = New-AzureRmLoadBalancerBackendAddressPoolConfig -Name "LB-backend"
$probe = New-AzureRmLoadBalancerProbeConfig -Name "HealthProbe" -Protocol Tcp -Port 80 -IntervalInSeconds 15 -ProbeCount 2
$inboundNATRule1= New-AzureRmLoadBalancerRuleConfig -Name "webserver" -FrontendIpConfiguration $frontendIP -Protocol Tcp -FrontendPort 80 -BackendPort 80 -IdleTimeoutInMinutes 15 -Probe $probe -BackendAddressPool $backendPool
$inboundNATPool1 = New-AzureRmLoadBalancerInboundNatPoolConfig -Name "RDP" -FrontendIpConfigurationId $frontendIP.Id -Protocol TCP -FrontendPortRangeStart 53380 -FrontendPortRangeEnd 53390 -BackendPort 3389

New-AzureRmLoadBalancer -ResourceGroupName $rg -Name "myLB" -Location $location -FrontendIpConfiguration $frontendIP -LoadBalancingRule $inboundNATRule1 -InboundNatPool $inboundNATPool1 -BackendAddressPool $backendPool -Probe $probe

## IP address config
$ipConfig = New-AzureRmVmssIpConfig -Name "my-ipaddress" -LoadBalancerBackendAddressPoolsId $backendPool.Id -SubnetId $vnet.Subnets[0].Id -LoadBalancerInboundNatPoolsId $inboundNATPool1.Id

# Attach the virtual network to the IP object
Add-AzureRmVmssNetworkInterfaceConfiguration -VirtualMachineScaleSet $vmssConfig -Name "network-config" -Primary $true -IPConfiguration $ipConfig

# Create the scale set with the config object (this step might take a few minutes)
New-AzureRmVmss -ResourceGroupName $rg -Name "myvmss" -VirtualMachineScaleSet $vmssConfig
```

Error Code

```
New-AzureRmVmss : Long running operation failed with status 'Failed'.
ErrorCode: DiskProcessingError
ErrorMessage: One or more errors occurred while preparing VM disks. See disk instance view for details.
StartTime: 8/21/2017 4:59:40 PM
EndTime: 8/21/2017 5:00:02 PM
OperationID: xxxxxxx-fda7-4f37-acbb-xxxxxxxx
Status: Failed
At line:1 char:1
+ New-AzureRmVmss -ResourceGroupName $rg -Name "myvmss" -VirtualMa ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [New-AzureRmVmss], ComputeCloudException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Compute.Common.ComputeCloudException,Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Compute.Automation.NewAzureRmVmss
```

I can't seems to figure out what exactly causing the problem, the same image was able to be used to create standalone VM.

Answer (score 0):

I have test it in my lab, your script works for me, here is my result:
[image]

> Get-AzureRmImage -ImageName image200817 -ResourceGroupName $rg

Does this image create by Azure VM?

If yes, we should use `waagent` command to delete machine specific files and data. SSH to your VM then type the following command:

```
sudo waagent -deprovision+user
```

**Note:**

> Only run this command on a VM that you intend to capture as an image.
>   It does not guarantee that the image is cleared of all sensitive
>   information or is suitable for redistribution. The +user parameter
>   also removes the last provisioned user account. If you want to keep
>   account credentials in the VM, just use -deprovision to leave the user
>   account in place.

After run this command completed, we can use CLI to create VM image, we can follow those steps:

1.Deallocate the VM

```
   az vm deallocate \
    --resource-group myResourceGroup \
    --name myVM
```

2.Mark the VM as generalized

```
az vm generalize \
  --resource-group myResourceGroup \
  --name myVM
```

3.create an image of the VM

```
az image create \
  --resource-group myResourceGroup \
  --name myImage --source myVM
```

After those script run completed, we can use your powershell script to deploy VMSS with that image.

More information about create an image of a virtual machine or VHD, please refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/linux/capture-image?toc=%2Fazure%2Fvirtual-machines%2Flinux%2Ftoc.json).

Comment: Just want to confirm the current situations.

Please feel free to let me know if you need further assistance.

Comment: Hi Jason, thanks so much for your input on my problems. For your information, the image was created from Centos 6.8 from azure which I installed additional packages and capture it as a custom image.  I have deployed the same image as single VM with no problem, but no in VMSS.

Comment: Yes, capture a image can use to create a single vm, if you not use waagent to remove the user and password and other data, we can't use it to create more than one Vm. So we should follow the answer to create the image. I had test with capture image, get the same error as you. Please try follow the steps to create image:)

Comment: Hi Jason, thank you so much for your input. I followed your instruction to capture a image of Centos 6.8 using `sudo waagent -deprovision+user` (previously I use the same command with -force). However I still having the same error after I tried to deployed as VMSS.

However the same procedures actually works on Ubuntu 16.04. The deployment of backend pools was successful. Now that I know the powershell scripts is working, the only thing is to find out why my Centos 6.8 doesn't work.

Comment: @SJYap I get same error with you when I use centos 6.8, I will do some test and would get back to you soon.